# Python Mocking assert_called not working

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing, mocking

I am able to successfully mock a function, and I am sure that the original is not called.  I added a huge print statement to the original function and when I mock it, this print is not called.  When I turn the mock back on, the print statement is not called.

However, my assert_called is failing saying it was never called.  Has anyone ever experienced something like this?

```
class FooTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    @mock.patch('MyObj.helper_function')
    def test_simple(self, mock_hf):

        my_obj = MyObj()

        # internally, this class imports HelperModule 
        # and the method calls helper_function
        my_obj.do_something()

        mock_hf.helper_function.assert_called()

        return
```

My error response

```
AssertionError: Expected 'helper_function' to have been called.
```

**Update**
I just added the following lines right before the assertion

```
    print mock_cw.method_calls
    print mock_cw.mock_calls
```

method_calls is an empty list, while mock_calls is a list with 1 item which is

```
[call(arg1_expected_for_helper_fn, arg2_expected_for_helper_fn)]
```

Yet the assert still fails

Comment: Is My_Obj.do_something() calling the My_Obj.helper_function()? Can you put a snippet of that code as well?

Comment: Yes, it does.  I mentioned that in the comment.  That code is pretty simple, I don't know if that will help.  Check out what I am about to update the question with.  That may help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that I was checking to see if `mock_hf.helper_function` was called, but `mock_hf` is already mapped to the `helper_function`.  I was more or less checking that `helper_function.helper_function` was called rather than just `helper_function`.

The assert line needed to be
`mock_hf.assert_called()`

Answer (score 4):

Usually an error like this is a result of not patching the correct location. Try to patch the object itself with this:

```
@patch.object(MyObj, "helper_function")
def test_simple(mock_hf):
    ...
```

Since MyObj is (assumed to be) imported at the top of the test file, this patches the method on that object directly.

Comment: While usually the correct answer for any patch related issues, it was an issue with how I was calling the assert method

Comment: Ah I see, that will do it!

Answer (score -1):

I see the original poster has done this, but for anyone else stumbling on this as I did...

Don't forget you need to wrap your expected calls in a `call` object e.g.

`mock_logger.assert_has_calls([call(expected_log_message_1), call(expected_log_message_2)])`

If you don't do that, it will complain that the expected call did not happen and you will spend ages comparing the output to try and work out why (as I did!).